# Comparing Values in HighCharts (not HighStock)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, highcharts

With HighStock, you have the option to compare values:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: { 
             compare: 'percent'
           },
},
```

From what I can tell, HighCharts does not have this functionality. Is there an easy way to compare values with HighCharts on the client side or am I better off doing all the calculations in my views?

Comment: If you can do the logic in the view, then it should be done in the view.

Comment: In the Highcharts this is not build-in, so you need to calculate these values on your own.